# ORA-00957: duplicate column name ERROR While Creating View

Tags: sql, oracle

I am getting ORA-00957: duplicate column name error while trying to create view. What is the problem ? How can I fix my query?

```
CREATE VIEW SIGN 
AS
    SELECT 
        CONTRACTS.CONTRACT_ID, CONTRACTS.PERSONNEL_ID, CONTRACTS.CUSTOMER_ID, 
        CUSTOMERS.FIRST_NAME, 
        PERSONNEL.FIRST_NAME, CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMER_ID, PERSONNEL.PERSONNEL_ID
    FROM 
        CONTRACTS, CUSTOMERS, PERSONNEL
    WHERE 
        (CONTRACTS.PERSONNEL_ID = PERSONNEL.PERSONNEL_ID) 
        AND (CONTRACTS.CUSTOMER_ID = CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMER_ID)
```

Comment: What part of the error do you not understand?

Comment: I can't find duplicate column part

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**almost 30 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 2):

First, learn to use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Second, views cannot have duplicates names, such as `PERSONNEL_ID` and `FIRST_NAME` in your view.

Third, table aliases make the query easier to write and read.

So:

```
CREATE VIEW SIGN AS
    SELECT c.CONTRACT_ID, c.PERSONNEL_ID, c.CUSTOMER_ID,
           cu.FIRST_NAME,
           p.FIRST_NAME as PERSONNEL_FIRST_NAME
    FROM CONTRACTS C JOIN
         CUSTOMERS CU
         ON C.CUSTOMER_ID = CU.CUSTOMER_ID JOIN
         PERSONNEL P
         ON C.PERSONNEL_ID = p.PERSONNEL_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Column names in a result set must be unique. Qualifying them with a table name does not make the column names any different, so

```
SELECT CONTRACTS.PERSONNEL_ID, PERSONNEL.PERSONNEL_ID...
```

will fail because `PERSONNEL_ID` is specified twice.

The following should work as you expect:

```
CREATE VIEW SIGN AS
  SELECT co.CONTRACT_ID,
         co.PERSONNEL_ID,
         cu.CUSTOMER_ID,
         p.FIRST_NAME
    FROM CONTRACTS co
    INNER JOIN CUSTOMERS cu
      ON cu.CUSTOMER_ID = co.CUSTOMER_ID
    INNER JOIN PERSONNEL p
      ON p.PERSONNEL_ID = co.PERSONNEL_ID
```